# Make Emacs access to HTTPS over Socks proxy

Tags: emacs, proxy, elisp, socks

This issue drove me crazy. I have a local SOCKSv5 proxy which is a gateway for all application on the system. I'd like to make `url-retrieve-synchronously` go though the SOCKS. With the following settings:

```
(setq socks-noproxy '("127.0.0.1"))
(setq socks-server '("Default server" "127.0.0.1" 8010 5))
(setq url-gateway-method 'socks)
```

The retrieve over plain HTTP works ok:

```
(url-retrieve-synchronously "http://gnu.org")
#<buffer  *http www.gnu.org:80*>
```

But it does not work for **HTTPS**:

```
(url-retrieve-synchronously "https://gnu.org")
```

It causes:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "make client process failed" "connection timed out" :name "gnu.org" :buffer #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> :host "gnu.org" :service 443 :nowait nil)
  make-network-process(:name "gnu.org" :buffer #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> :host    "gnu.org" :service 443 :nowait nil)
  open-network-stream("gnu.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "gnu.org" 443)
  open-gnutls-stream("gnu.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "gnu.org" 443)
  network-stream-open-tls("gnu.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "gnu.org" 443 (:type tls :nowait nil))
  open-network-stream("gnu.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "gnu.org" 443 :type tls :nowait nil)
  byte-code("\306\211\n\307>\203$
```

**Question**: how to make HTTPS work over socks in Emacs? My version is 24.2.50/W32

I understand that for some reason an original `open-network-stream` is used instead `socks-open-network-stream`. I tried to breakpoint `url-open-stream` using *edebug* but did not manage to understand why the breakpoint is not triggered. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tracked the problem out. There is definitely a bug in Emacs. There is a macro `url-https-create-secure-wrapper` which creates a wrapper over `url-http` function; in the wrapper a value of `url-gateway-method` is overwritten with `tls` value. This causes a skipping of using SOCKS and using direct gateway for connection instead. Currently I have no idea how to hack/workaround the problem.

Comment: redefine `url-https-create-secure-wrapper`?

Comment: Won't work; at least with my knowledge of ELisp. If I redefine `url-https-create-secure-wrapper` the connection will go through SOCKS but with plain HTTP negotiation not HTTPS. The wrapper should use SOCKS proxy as a main network stream but for HTTPS.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` if you've not already done so? (assuming it's not already fixed?)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use program `proxychains` to start emacs from command line, `proxychains` supports HTTP socks4 and socks5 proxy protocols. The code may be:

`proxychains emacs &`

Needless to say you have to configure your proxy setting in proxychains instead of in emacs.

PS: Don't forget to set proxychains in `quiet_mode` in its configure file(`/etc/proxychains.conf`), or the verbose output may annony you. It's not the default set at least on Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

GamerH2o - I've never got

```
proxychains emacs &
```

to work. For me, I have to do

```
proxychains bash-script.sh &
```

where the bash-script.sh is a script

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/emacs --debug-init --geometry 83X40 --no-splash & ;;
exit 0
```

which launches emacs. My actual script is a little more complicated than above since I include various options, but that's the general idea. I can now use w3m or eww as "emacs internet-browsers". My passage through the dns servers is echo'd in the xterm. (I'm using tor rather than "free anon servers".)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug above Emacs 26.3 in `url-http` function, the signature of `url-http` look like this:

```
(defun url-http (url callback cbargs &optional retry-buffer gateway-method) ...)
```

The optional `gateway-method` argument try to overwrite `url-gateway-method` but been wrong coded:

```
(connection (url-http-find-free-connection 
                (url-host url)
                (url-port url)
                gateway-method))
```

The right way to do that:

```
(connection (url-http-find-free-connection 
                 (url-host url)
                 (url-port url)
                 (or gateway-method url-gateway-method)))
```

In Emacs 24 version, `url-gateway-method` local variable had hard coded to `'tls`

```
(defmacro url-https-create-secure-wrapper (method args)
  `(defun ,(intern (format (if method "url-https-%s" "url-https") method)) ,args
    ,(format "HTTPS wrapper around `%s' call." (or method "url-http"))
    (let ((url-gateway-method 'tls))
      (,(intern (format (if method "url-http-%s" "url-http") method))
       ,@(remove '&rest (remove '&optional args))))))
```

The fix for Emacs version >= 25:

```
(defadvice url-http (around url-http-around activate disable)
        "Fix the `url-gateway-method' bug in `url-http'."
        (if (eq 'socks url-gateway-method)
            (let ((gateway-method url-gateway-method))
              ad-do-it)
          ad-do-it))
```

The fix for Emacs version < 25:

```
(defvar *url-gateway-method* nil
  "Alias of `url-gateway-method' used to fix the bug in `url-http'.")

(defadvice url-http (around url-http-around compile)
  "Fix the `url-gateway-method' bug in `url-https'."
  (let ((url-gateway-method (if (eq *url-gateway-method* 'socks)
                                'socks
                              'tls)))
    ad-do-it))
```

Finally, you can review the fix here: https://github.com/junjiemars/.emacs.d/blob/cc/config/sockets.el.

Answer (score 0):

Create ~/.emacs.d/w3m.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

proxychains /usr/bin/w3m "$@"
```

Custom w3m:

```
(setq w3m-command "~/.emacs.d/w3m.sh")
```

Then only w3m use proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It fixed in emacs current version (checked 25.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

My Emacs version is 28.1, I tried the following config,
and it worked like a charm, btw, I use v2ray in the background.

```
(setq url-proxy-services
  '(("no_proxy" . "^.*example.com")
    ("https" . "localhost:1087")
    ("http" . "localhost:1087")
    ;; socks not working, @see url-default-find-proxy-for-url
    ;; ("socks5" . "localhost:1080")
    ))
```